# how to know if mouse moves on an object

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

I have an square object in my screen:

```
glVertex3d(-0.1, -0.1, -0.1);
glVertex3d(0.1, -0.1, -0.1);
glVertex3d(0.1, 0.1, -0.1);
glVertex3d(-0.1, 0.1, -0.1);
```

Now i want to know if the mouse moves on this object.

Answer (score 0):

If its just a plain square then its best to manually transform your 4 vertices into screen space (by multiplying them with your model-view-projection-matrices), then also transforming your mouse coordinates into a range of -1 to 1, and finally checking if your mouse coordinates within the polygon you described.
Also see [gluProject](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml) for helping you to transform points from 3D space to screen space.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to be mentioned is that you should know in what space you will perform your calculations. Mouse pointer has location acording to screen or window space and your object (box in this example) has model space coordinates.

You have to select one space and transform all your coordinates into selected space.

Here is a blog post describing some of issues: http://bartlomiejfilipek.blogspot.com/2012/06/select-mouse-opengl.html

Answer (score 0):

i think gluPickMatrix is what you are looking for.

you can find more details [here](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html)